# Code to Read and write array into text file in Xcode 10.2

Tags: arrays, swift

I am a beginner to Swift and Xcode, trying to do simple data persistance app. I am looking for code to Read and write array into text file. The idea is to have an initial array with one piece of info. During the table view load, if the text file has data, then load the data into table view. If no data, then show the table view the data from the array. As user enters the data, rewrite the text file with data changes in the array.

I have tried some code, but running into problem of the file being recreated every time, so the code is not reading from text file.

```
// This function reads from text file and makes the array.
func readDataFromFile(){
    let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(strFileName)
    print(fileURL as Any)

    //Adding this new as the path seems to change everytime, need fixing here.
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let pathComponent = fileURL!.appendingPathComponent(strFileName)
    let filePath = pathComponent.path
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath){
        try allToys = NSMutableArray(contentsOf: fileURL!) as! [String]
    }
    else
    {
        writeArrayToFile()
    }
}

// This is to write array of data to a file
func writeArrayToFile()
{
    let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(strFileName)
    (allToys as NSArray).write(to: fileURL!, atomically: true)
}
```

Expectation: Data is being read from the same file everytime
Actual: A new dynamic path is created everytime, so the data is not being retained.

New code

let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first

```
func writeArrayToFile(){
    let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    (allToys as NSArray).write(to: fileURL!, atomically: true)
}

func readDataFromFile(){
    let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let fm = FileManager()
    if(fileURL != nil) {
        if(!(fm.fileExists(atPath: (fileURL?.path)!))){
            let temp = NSMutableArray(contentsOf: fileURL!)
            if (temp != nil) {
                allToys = NSMutableArray(contentsOf: fileURL!) as! [String]
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, Is there a way to use relative or absolute path instead of dynamic path?

Comment: Well you are appending `strFileName` twice in `readDataFromFile`

Comment: Hi Joakim, thanks for the comment, I changed code to do this, I am still seeing the same problem.. This may sound stupid, I cant figure out a way to paste my new code..

Comment: Added new code - still same problem.. any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you are trying to read the file only if it doesn't exists, `if(!(fm.fileExists`

Since I realised this when re-writing and trying to understand the code I might as well post my version of your code. Note that since I didn't fully understand your class/struct definition I made the functions more independent by using parameters and return values rather than properties

I skipped `dir` as property and made it into a local variable, here is my write function

```
func write(_ array: [Any], toFile fileName: String){
    guard let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        fatalError("No Document directory found")
    }
    let fileUrl = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    (array as NSArray).write(to: fileUrl, atomically: true)
}
```

and the read function was simplified by not using the FileManager

```
func read(_ fromFile: String) -> [String]? {
    guard let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        fatalError("No Document directory found")
    }
    let fileUrl = dir.appendingPathComponent(fromFile)
    if let temp = NSArray(contentsOf: fileUrl) {
        return temp as? [String]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Testing the code

```
let fileName = "toys.txt"
var allToys = ["Duck", "Playstation", "iPhone"]

write(allToys, toFile: fileName)

if let saved = read(fileName) {
    allToys = saved
    allToys.append("Lego")
    write(allToys, toFile: fileName)
}
```